# blackberry tablet SDK installation in 64 bit W7

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, blackberry, sdk

I am trying to install the blackberry table OS SDK on my windows 7 machine (x64) however the program is not compatible. Is there a way to install it in x86 (32 bit) mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found! Solution [here](http://blog.swfjunkie.com/2010/10/getting-started-blackberry-playbook-development-setup/)